# urlencoding Chinese character to url

Tags: php, html, curl, encoding, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to translate a chinese character to english but i think there is issue when it comes to encoding.

How do i pass the Chinese character to Microsoft so they can translate it and return me the text in English? I cant seem to send the Chinese characters over because of the encoding? I tried detecting the encoding type.

Chinese Character in $completeColours

```
橘色,灰色,深蓝,绿色
```

URLencoded text
    %26%2327224%3B%26%2333394%3B%2C%26%2328784%3B%26%2333394%3B%2C%26%2328145%3B%26%2334013%3B%2C%26%2332511%3B%26%2333394%3B

returned result

```
&#27224;&#33394;,&#28784;&#33394;,&#28145;&#34013;,&#32511;&#33394;
```

Code

```
// Prepare variables
$text = urlencode($completeColours);
echo $text;
$from = 'zh-CHT';
$to = 'en';

// Prepare cURL command
$key = 'xxx';
$ch = curl_init('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=%27'.$text.'%27&From=%27'.$from.'%27&To=%27'.$to.'%27');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':'.$key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


// Parse the XML response
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = explode('<d:Text m:type="Edm.String">', $result);
$result = explode('</d:Text>', $result[1]);
$result = $result[0];

echo $result;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i pass the Chinese character to Microsoft so they can translate it and return me the text in English? I cant seem to send the Chinese characters over because of the encoding. , Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the subject and, to avoid that, I decided to force my Chinese users to write address in english with occidental chars.

Like this :

[image: MyPrettyCMS Front office capture, see address in address bar]

Here the menu editor with the "on the fly" friendly url builder :

[image: MyPrettyCMS Friendly URL Menu Builder]

I went on Badu with Firefox, Chrome and IE.
As you can see, Firefox is able to display Chinese symbols in address bar but not Chrome and IE so, I ask myself, what the best for SEO ?

- Use occidental chars to display an address in english ?
- Use codes as you do ?
- Use occidental chars but write phonetic chinese symbol as in the chinese input system ?

Now I choose the first option but I'm not sure it's the best one.

here the 3 captures :

[image: Baidu under IE]

[image: Baidu under Chrome]

[image: Baidu under Firefox]